# Extracting entry from a Java HashMap based on equality of a field in the key type

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Java HashMap of type `<MyType,Double>`. The `MyType` class has two fields `foo` (of type String)and `bar`(of type Double). The equals and hashcode methods for `MyType` use only `foo`. Now given an object `A` of type `MyType` I need to get the matching entry from the Hashmap. What that means is

```
MyType A = new MyType();
A.foo = "foo";
A.bar = 0.0;

MyType B = new MyType();
B.foo = "foo";
B.bar = 1.0;

Map<MyType,Double> myMap = new HashMap<MyType,Double>();
myMap.put(B,5.0)
```

I need to extract the key `B`(and eventually its bar value) from `myMap` based on it's equality with `A` (since their `foo` values are same) i.e. a function of the form

```
Double getBar(MyType type,  Map<MyType,Double> map)
```

such that

```
getBar(A,myMap) returns 1.0
```

What is the best way to do that? I am not too sure of how this thing is designed in the first place but I am looking for an efficient way of doing this since `myMap` is expected to be really huge.

UPDATE: A slightly bigger context here is this. I have a set of MyType objects (say S). An external function works on it and creates a HashMap called myMap which calculates and associates a quantity of type Double with each object in the set. It also updates the bar field of each object in the set. What I get back is myMap. Now I need to update each element in my original set S such that each element's bar value is replaced by what the bar value of the corresponding entry in the returned myMap is. So for each A in S I need to read the corresponding B in myMap, get its bar, and then set the bar of A to be same as bar of B.

Comment: Do you have to use a `HashMap`?  If you could use a `TreeMap` instead, you can provide a custom `Comparator<MyType>` that would implement equality on foo values.

Comment: The map can already figure out A and B are equal because of teh equals method in MyType. No?

Comment: @atlantis on lines 6 and 7 I think you want to set `B.foo` not `A.foo` since you've already set the `A` values and just declared `B`

Comment: @atlantis also, wouldn't `getBar` not even require the map?  couldn't you just return `A.bar`?

Comment: @MartyE No. A.bar is not same as B.bar. I need getBar to return B.bar based on the fact that A.foo is equal to B.foo and hence A and B are same

Comment: atlantis, I just can't see any reason why you wouldn't simply use `myMap.values().get(A)`. Am I missing something here? The only off thing is that you are using a map where your use case seems to be calling for nothing but a set.

Comment: @atlantis ah, I think I get where you're going.  This is a bit of a hack, but you could use `Map.getKeys()` to find the one your looking for, then call the appropriate `key.bar`.  Though I think you're better off altering or adding another `Map` such as `Map<string, MyType>`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik myMap.get(A) will give me the value against the key which is equal to A. In this case, the value stored against B which 5.0 which is not what I am after. I need the bar value of B to be returned.

Comment: Yes, things are becoming clearer. You need to look up a key by another object equal to it. If you had another `Map<MyType, MyType>`, then this would be very easy to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the `hashCode` and `equals` based on the `foo` (which is what you indicate you are doing) then in your example `A` and `B` would end up in the same bucket in the hashmap.
As a result `getBar(A,myMap);` would return `5.0` because that is what you put in the map- `B`.
I mean you can search for `B` using `A` but then each `put` would replace the previous one and I am not sure from your OP what your actual requirement is

Update:

```
Double getBar(MyType type,  Map<MyType,Double> map){  
    if(map.containsKey(type)){   
         for(MyType k:map.keySet()){  
              if(k.equals(type)){  
                 return k.bar;  
              }
         }
    }
    return -1.0;
}
```

**Update 2:**
It seems that what you need is a way to access the keys in your `Map` directly. You could use do the following:
Define:

```
class Holder{  
    MyType type;  
    Double value;  
}
```

and have `HashMap<MyType,Holder>` instead. So in your method that does the calculation you update the map to add the result in the `Holder` object where you also store the `type`. I.e. instead of `myMap.put(B,5.0);` you do: `myMap.put(B,new Holder(B,5.0));`

So you will have:

```
Double getBar(MyType type,  Map<MyType,Holder> map){   
     return map.get(type).type.bar;    
}
```

You have extra space requirement for storing the `type` as part of the value of the map as well but you will have gotten rid of the looping to actually find the `type` as it is now

Comment: You are right about A and B to be the same from the pov of the map which is what we want. I think you meant myMap.get(A) will return 5.0 which is correct. But I need the method getBar to be able to take the map and the object A as parameters and extract the key corresponding to the entry of {B=5.0} which is B(with foo="foo" and bar=1.0) and then return its bar value which is  1.0

Comment: @atlantis:See the update.This code will give you `1.0`. Is this what you need?

Comment: map.get(type) returns a Double. The value of the key B i.e. 5.0

Comment: @atlantis:See update.I didn't understand what you mean and to be honest I don't understand what is the requirement you are trying to implement

Comment: @atlantis:Returning negative on not existing but you can do according to your needs e.g. throw exception etc

Comment: Your update does seem to be the only way to do it given the data structures. I will accept it as an answer although I am not going to use this - not just not pretty, will turn out to be prohibitively costly to search through the keySet of the huge myMap each time.

Comment: @atlantis:Why don't you give more information about what problem you are trying to solve?Perhaps you should be using another datastructure

Answer (score 2):

If you need to look up a `Whatever` by its `Foo`, you *must* use a `Map<Foo, Whatever>`.  Anything else will be, at best, a hack trying to shove something that isn't a `Map` into a `Map`.

But the point is, the `Map` interface isn't designed to be used the way you're trying to use it.  It's meant to look up the *values* based on only the *keys* you put in.  You might be able to force it to work that way, but at best you'll end up with an unmaintainable, awkward hack that's probably more difficult than doing things correctly to begin with.

It mostly looks like you should be using a `Map<String, MyTypeAndDouble>` for some custom class that contains both a `MyType` and a `Double`.

Comment: But Louis, to me it appears that everything is just right: he has a class with two properties, only one of which is partaking in the equality relation. He'll be using that class as a hashmap key and everything will come out right.

Comment: The problem isn't just his key -- it's his value.  You can't look up keys from a `Map` (at least, not with the hash table) -- only values.

Comment: Yes, I realized that now. He would need a `Map<MyType,MyType>` to get this. I always forget that `Set.get` doesn't exist.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I see your point and that's why I said I am not particularly happy with this design. But all I have right now is a map of MyType vs Double. A slightly bigger picture of the task at hand is to update the bar of A by getting the bar value from the corresponding MyType object(B here) stored in myMap.

Comment: I'm not just unhappy with your design.  I'm saying that it's *not possible* to do what you're trying to do, with this design, short of a direct linear search through the `keySet()` of the map.  (If you had a `TreeMap`...there _might_ be dirty, dirty hacks to do it in logarithmic time, but you don't.)

Comment: atlantis, use `Map.getEntry(key).getKey()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: There's no such method as `Map.getEntry`. ;)  In `TreeMap`, there's `ceilingEntry(key)`, which is what I'd use for the dirty hack, but that's about it.

Comment: It's there, but it's package-private. There are several hacks to get it: reflection or subclassing with your own class in the `java.util` package. I'm really frustrated with this not being exposed in the public API.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's what I thought but decided to ask before abandoning the effort.

Comment: Eh.  I...honestly think leaving it out was the right call, to force people to use more consistent abstractions, but I can understand your position.

Comment: But in general, a method that gets a set member equal to the argument is surely a consistent abstraction. For example, in Clojure it's **the** function to use on a set. There, the set object itself is a function that, applied to an argument, gives this result.

Answer (score 0):

Well this isn't pretty and requires iterating through the Map but it should get you to the value of bar in the scenario you're describing. (This assumes your equals() method is as you described it, looking only at the value of foo to determine object equality).

```
public Double getBar(MyType type,  Map<MyType,Double> map) {
  for (MyType entry : map.keySet()) {  
    if (entry.equals(type)) {
      return entry.getBar(); // or whatever your accessor is for bar
    } 
  }
  return null;  // or whatever value you want to return if it doesn't find a key
}
```

Comment: Iterating is a fail. OP is aware of this but wants an O(1) solution.

Comment: No disagreement on the iterating, but as has already been noted in other comments, without additional context around the issue itself it is difficult to suggest alternative implementations.  Given that I am just doing my best to directly answer the question asked.

Comment: @Bionic_Geek Point taken. There doesn't seem to be a nice way to do this given the state of things. The crux of your solution though is no different from what user384706 answered.

Comment: Understood - I think he and I wrote it up at the same time, I just kept editing to throw in the comments, etc..  no big deal as long as you feel you question is answered.  :)